# how do i call a bash script from inside an init.d script?

Tags: openrc

Is it possible to call a bash script from inside an init.d script in linux? 
I need to call it and also return results.  Sorry, I'm not a sysadmin and I've never created an init.d script. Right now I'm looking at other init.d scripts i see on my box and trying to see how it works.

Comment: is your system using systemd? (these days more likely than not) if so, contemplate on something like this: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux

Comment: @Theophrastus cool.  I am trying to create a custom service in fact.  Thanks..

Comment: With systemd the procedure to create a custom service is different from create a simple sh script

Answer (score -2):

Call a script from a script?
Is a non-sense,is like hear "i want to drive a car using a car,how to do?"
What is a script?
A script is a ascii text file which need a shell to be "interpreted" or running.
It can contain commands,but also loop(while,until) and other constructs like if..else..fi or case..esac.
If you mean "i want to run a script" you have two ways

```
bash /etc/init.d/"script I want to run"
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/"script I want to run"
```

WARNING!Running some scripts as root without know what script is
can damage your system.
Before running a script read it's contents with

```
less /etc/init.d/myscript
```

Comment: The OP's question is reasonable.  Scripts in `/etc/init.d` have particular conventions, and it is prudent to not want to treat them like any other shell script without more information.

Comment: Thank you... I think.?  I guess it can sound like non-sense if you're familiar with openrc-run ... and bash.  But like I said.  I'm not.  Hence the question.  And re: the warning - I'm making the scripts that will be called...so I know exactly what it will do.

Comment: Is your whole first paragraph, just a rant over the use of the word "run" vs "call"?